# Movies and Videos on my clients website Amazon Ec2, S3 and Glacier Storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud

My clients wants to build a website where in users can download videos. 
We have kept, Max file size =800 MB.

S3 and EC2 costs us bomb and we really can not afford these services.

Glacier storage on Amazon however is cheap but my client says will it affect quality. In my opinion it is nothing to do with quality we are using amazon just to store the data (movies) and it is  only when a user wants to download the movie fully we should bother about performance etc.

Is my narration to my client is correct? I spent hours in reading the documentation. Please help me if you know the correct solution on how to store video files on Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

Glacier is not designed for this, its designed for long term archival with no or very little access. Accessing files from glacier will become expensive.

S3/Cloudfront is your best option within AWS. To save some money you an use Reduced Redundancy Storage (RRS). In addition, convert the videos to lower quality to save storage space.